# Scope Provider for Nested Objects

Tags: xtext

I am trying to program a scope provider for an Entity mapping Model where Entities attributes can reference other entities and mapping part of the DSL can use the attributes of the nested entities.

I followed the instructions in this [blog](https://dietrich-it.de/xtext/2013/05/18/xtext-and-dot/path-expressions/) and it works perfectly but I have complication with QualifiedNames.

My DSL looks like the following.

```
Model:
  elements+=BaseElement*;

BaseElement:
  Context | Entity | Mapping;

QualifiedName:
  ID ('.' ID)*;

QualifiedNameWithWildcard:
  QualifiedName '.*'?; 

Context:
  'context' name=QualifiedName '{'
  entities+=Entity* 
  '}';

Entity:
   'entity' name=ID 
   fields+=Field*;

Field:
Attribute | Reference
;

Attribute:
  name=ID type=TYPE_ENUM
;

Reference:
 name=ID type=[Entity]
;

enum TYPE_ENUM:
  INT | LONG | STRING | BOOLEAN | UUID
;

Mapping:
  'mapping' name=ID
   mappings+=FieldMapping*
;

FieldMapping:
  name=ID '=>' ref=DotExpression
;

DotExpression returns Ref:
  EntityRef ({DotExpression.ref=current}  "." tail=[Field])*
;

EntityRef returns Ref:
  {EntityRef} entity=[Entity]
;
```

and with this model everything works perfectly.

```
entity entityA {
  x STRING
  y STRING
  z INT
}

entity EntityB  {
  a INT
  b STRING
}

entity EntityC {
  m STRING
  n INT
  p EntityA
}

mapping Absender
  Sender_PostCode => Entity.p.x
```

The complication arises, if I use the Context element and change the DSL accordingly for the Qualified Name.

```
  context org.test.example {
    entity entityA {
      x STRING
      y STRING
      z INT
    }

    entity EntityB  {
      a INT
      b STRING
    }

    entity EntityC {
      m STRING
      n INT
      p EntityA
    }
  }

mapping Absender
  Sender_PostCode => Entity.p.x
```

and language change.

```
Reference:
  name=ID type=[Entity|QualifiedName]
;

EntityRef returns Ref:
  {EntityRef} entity=[Entity|QualifiedName]
;
```

Now Eclipse smart help is not able to identify the 'Entity.p.x'.

I guess QualifiedName confuses the parser for DotExpression for the following ScopeProvider.

```
    @Override
public IScope getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if(context instanceof DotExpression) {
        DotExpression dotExpression = (DotExpression) context;
        
        Ref head = dotExpression.getRef();
        return recursive(head);
    }
    return super.getScope(context, reference);
}

private IScope recursive(Ref head) {
    if(head instanceof EntityRef) {
        EntityRef entity = (EntityRef) head;
        return Scopes.scopeFor(entity.getEntity().getFields());
    } else if(head instanceof DotExpression) {
        DotExpression nextDE = (DotExpression) head;
        if(nextDE.getTail() instanceof Attribute) {
            return IScope.NULLSCOPE; 
        } else if(nextDE.getTail() instanceof Reference) {
            Reference ref = (Reference) nextDE.getTail();
            return Scopes.scopeFor(ref.getType().getFields());
        } else if(nextDE.getTail() instanceof DotExpression){
            DotExpression tail = (DotExpression) nextDE.getTail();
            return recursive((tail.getRef()));
        } else {
            return IScope.NULLSCOPE;
        }
    } else {
        return IScope.NULLSCOPE;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how can I integrate the QualifiedName with DotExpression?

Comment: how do you know if you write a.b.c.d.e that a.b.c is the package, d the entity and e the field and not a the the package, b the entity and c,d and e are fields. also check the ambiguity error on generation

Comment: maybe you can use different syntax for dot expression like  -> or :: or ...

Comment: yeah, I had to go for '->', then it works, I was hoping there might be another way. Like I can somehow programmatically match first 'org.test.example' for package then the rest for EntityA for 'org.test.example.EntityC.p.x' but if you say it hopeless to make it work this way, I can live with '->' also. I wonder how java does, if 'p' would be static, 'org.test.example.EntityC.p.x' would be a valid statement for Java parser.

Comment: you can implement scoping and linking to basically have
ref=[SomeCommonObject] for all elements in the chain and then basically find out the first completely matching chain to the entity and then start the normal scoping
i know that was done in some projects, but i dont know if any of them are open source and have never done myself

Comment: Side note: I think the branch `else if(nextDE.getTail() instanceof DotExpression){...}` is a dead code because `tail` is a reference to a `Field` which is either an `Attribute` XOR a `Reference` -- so `DotExpression` is out of scope (pun intended:-))

Comment: Yeah, I thought also that should be dead code, but I guarantee that my debugging suggest otherwise. if the expression is  not single dot but 'EntityC.p.x.y.z.t' so deep nested, it is going to that branch to resolve 't', may be there is another problem in my code or language definition but at the moment it is not dead code.